# Google Adsense Responsive Ads Not Showing

Tags: html, css, adsense

In the following link [here](http://syriantc.com/abohani/index/general/), i have 3 ads, Right / Left / Header Ads. They're using Responsive Units, the status is "Active", the problem is the Responsive ads are not showing, Googling revealed that it's caused by the CSS theming, maybe the Ad units are not taking the size of the parent div .

I've tried the following :

```
    <div class="right-ad">
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>  
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:inline"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-1588985522291479"
 data-ad-slot="8975496541"
 data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</div>
```

2 :

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>  
<ins class="right-ad"
 style="display:inline"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-1588985522291479"
 data-ad-slot="8975496541"
 data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Still blank, the CSS is as the following ( min 950px ) :

```
            margin-right: 1%;
            position: relative; 
            width: 13%;
            height: 100%;  
            margin-top:1em;
            float:right;
            border-top-left-radius: 2px;
            border-top-right-radius: 2px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
            box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0px 2px 4px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0px 0px 3px;
```

Why it's still blank ?

Edit :

```
</div>  

<div class="left-ad">
 <script async 
 src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
 <ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:block"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-1588985522291479"
 data-ad-slot="8975496541"
 data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
 <script>
 (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
 </script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ins class="right-ad"
 style="display:inline"
```

Did you add this to the ad's HTML? You are not supposed to change the ad code. For `data-ad-format="auto"` the ad will adapt to the container's size. Simply remove what you added to the ad code and change the container instead. In your case, the `<div class="right-ad">` div.

This is what a regular ad code looks like

```
<div class="my-container" style="width: 500px; height: 300px">

  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
  <ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXX"
     data-ad-slot="XXXXXXXXXXX"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
  <script>
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  </script>

</div>
```

So, your `style="display:inline"` should be

```
style="display:block"
```

Comment: This worked! thanks!, but it's smaller than the div size, also the div went above the original place .

Comment: You only see it as smaller. The div is the "max size" for the ad to fit in, but if there are smaller ads that bid more, then they will be added automatically. Other people in other places may see other ads than you do. Adsense will try different sizes of ads that fit in the `<div>` you put it in, and automatically serve the ads that are most profitable. Also depends on the screen size of the device the ad is viewed on. Remember to make your <div> a `max-width` and not a fixed `width` so its responsive to different screen sizes.

Comment: In the CSS, I've made a responsive design for the div, I've seen in a lot of websites where the Ad really adapt the div specs, like the rounded corners and the shadow. In this, the ad doesn't adapt the shadow, size, or the rounder corners, first step to make it work done, thanks, but the main goal for the design still having problems, any ideas ? .

Comment: The ad will adapt, but only if there aren't any better small ads. Sometimes smaller ads will have better revenue, so they will be shown. You best change is if you make your max container size a common ad size, like 300x250 or 300x600 etc. Because there are many ads that have that size and will fit in those places.

Answer (score -2):

My suggestions : in ad code ,

```
 display : inline-block
```

and remove
     `data-ad-format="auto"`

and if your parent dive size is smaller than available Ad units then some times Ad will not show

Comment: 175 x 643, in (min 950px ), I'm gonna try this.