# A new Unit created in Google adsense isn't working

Tags: ads, adsense, google-ads-api

I created this new `unit` today in my adsense account but it's not showing up. When I change the `data-ad-slot` ID to an old working `data-ad-slot` ID, the ad shows up. This new ID won't load any ad.

My google adsense account is 7-8 years old and I haven't created a new unit since. Or what could I be possibly doing wrong in creating a new unit?!

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- RightSidebar -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-123"
     data-ad-slot="12345"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don’t worry sometime it happens, 
Just put adsense code on the page run page from browser. Refresh it two or three times.
If it is not displaying ads, leave it and check it again and do same process.
I also got ads on new adsense code after many time page views.
I think answer may not help you, but I am sharing my experiences that I used generally.
***Please Read this...***
[Discussion on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482785/google-adsense-responsive-ads-not-showing)